# Visualize the Current spanning Tree of the Switches with the Help of Netmiko or Napalm

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, graphviz, netmiko, napalm

Hallo i am working on a project with netmiko and i would like to visualize the current Spanning tree of the switches
is there a way to this ? or library ?